# Using Cmake with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, ide, cmake, qt-creator

I would like to use `Qt creator` and `Cmake` together (please, don't ask me about my motivation, accept this as a given.)

I successfully set up Qt creator to use cmake "Cmake": see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html),    [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html) and [this](http://apachelog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/qt-creator-cmake-wizards/) documents regarding how I did that.

I successfully create `hello world` project, but I can't create files in project,
only add existing files to project tree and after that adding it to cmake list.
Standard operation of Qt creator "Add New..." doesn't work and I can't find why.

Is there anybody who uses Qt creator and "Cmake" together? Is the combination actually possible?

Note: I'm using Qt creator v2.4.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add files using glob expression in your CMakeLists.txt, like this:

```
file(GLOB SRC . *.cpp)
add_executable (your_exe_name ${SRC})
```

Cmake will pick your new cpp files next time you run it and QtCreator will show them in the project browser.

**Update**

This solution may be useful but as noted in comments - this is not a good practice. Every time somebody add new source file and commit changes, you need to rerun cmake to build all the sources. Usually I just `touch` one of the *CMakeLists.txt* files if my build is broken after I pool recent changes from repository. After that `make` will run `cmake` automatically and I didn't need to run it by hands. Despite of that I think that explicit source lists in *CMakeLists.txt* is a good thing, they called thing CMake **Lists** for a reason.

Comment: Keep in mind though, that it's considered a bad practice for CMake to use globing for collecting source files.

Comment: I'm using file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC  *.cpp)

Comment: CMake is quite smart in running itself from a makefile. I've never had to manually run CMake and I use globs constantly...

Comment: What CMake version do you use?

Answer (score 10):

When you add new files in QtCreator using the "New File or Project..." dialog it only creates the files on disk, it doesn't automatically add the files to the CMakeLists.txt.  You need to do this by hand by editing the CMakeLists.txt file.

The next time you build the project, CMake will be re-run, and QtCreator will pick up the new files and show them in the project browser.

Comment: May be I don't have been enough cleared
I search for way to create files in directory. Right button on folder ->add item and etc.This don't work for me when i using cmake

Comment: @themean - I took your question to be: Is it possible to add files to a CMake based project in QtCreator? And if so, how do you do it? If I've misunderstood this please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I've clarified my answer a bit does this help?

Comment: Okay it is work but no point for me. I aways can duplicate some .cpp and rename him(faster way). I want to work with qt creator like normal ide
I searching for plugin but the only think i found is [this](http://blogs.kde.org/node/3913)

Comment: May be soon i will can found [solution](http://blog.vcreatelogic.com/2010/06/moving-to-cmake/) of the problme

Comment: I don't think you'll find an IDE out there that automatically adds files to a generic CMakeLists.txt.  There's a lot of different ways a CMakeLists.txt file can be formatted and writing a plugin for an IDE to do this would be incredibly difficult IMO.  Also in my experience with QtCreator + CMake, the only major piece of functionality you lose is the ability for the IDE to update the CMakeList.txt file in an automated fashion, which isn't a huge deal for me given what it provides (code navigation, code completion). But thats just my opinion.

Comment: May be you are right may be not. Befor Qt creator i use kdevelop. This ide work perfectly with cmake but it's only for linux(may be)
[kdevelop](http://kdevelop.org/)

Answer (score 5):

I solve this problem that I added new files in standard way (CTRL+N), then added needed files in CMakeLists. After that, right click on project in project tree view and choose option Run CMake. After this, files showed in project list tree. Only build was not enough.

Answer (score 3):

I tested here and happened the same behavior because those options you were asking were really disabled.

Use File -> "New File or Project..." or CTRL+N to add new files and after that add to CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding an updated answer for newer versions of QtCreator (4.x, I don't know precisely which release but at least from 4.7). In the *Tools > Options...* menu, choose the *Build & Run* section and then the *CMake* tab. You will see the *Adding Files* settings, and you can set it to *Copy file paths* :

[image]

This way, when you want to add a new file to your project, in the *Project* view, right click on the desired CMake Executable/Library's name and select *Add New...*, go through the *Add dialog*, and when you'll validate the dialog, QtCreator will open *CMakeLists.txt* in the *Editor* view. Finally, paste the content of the clipboard at the end of the corresponding source file list and save *CMakeLists.txt*. The CMake project will be parsed, and your new file will show up in the *Project* view.

Comment: I don't see this option in QT Creator 4.5.2.

Comment: I don't precisely know when this option has been added. I've been using it for a couple of years now. When I wrote the answer the latest version of QT Creator was 4.7, I will edit my answer accordingly.