# How to use a build system other than qmake with a Qt project?

Tags: qt, build-system

In qtcreator a template qt project has a simple .pro configuration file.
From .pro file qmake utility generates Makefiles each of which contains lots of includes for every qt dependent source file:

```
release/moc_MainWindow.cpp: src/controller/Controller.hpp \
...
        ../../../../Qt/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow \
        ../../../../Qt/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h \
... 100 lines here ...
        ../../../../Qt/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h \
        ../../../../Qt/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h \
        src/view/qt/MainWindow.hpp
```

I have difficulties configuring .pro files so I decided to configure a qt project with another build system: make, automake, cmake for example.

Is there a way to configure any build system automatically for including lots of qt header files? Or to not include them but build qt project without qtcreator?

My question is different from [Using Cmake with Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415761/using-cmake-with-qt-creator) because i don't need a qt creator to present to solve my problem

Comment: Read the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-other.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Cmake with Qt Creator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415761/using-cmake-with-qt-creator)

Comment: Qt Creator is not a build system!

Comment: "I have difficulties configuring .pro files" Perhaps you should ask about your real problem first. You can use `make` directly, but you'll have to write everything by hand and these are not tiny makefiles, and they are specific to a given installation of Qt. There are really only three alternatives for building with Qt: qmake, cmake and [qbs](https://wiki.qt.io/Qbs). I think that Qbs holds the most promise, although it's underdocumented and you'll have to read examples to comprehend how it works.

Comment: >>Qt Creator is not a build system! I mean qmake ofcourse

Comment: I think creating separate build system for a library is a bad design, so i prefer to use cmake.

Comment: @KubaOber The assertion that "there are really only three alternatives for building with Qt" is simply not true. For example, [SCons](http://www.scons.org) has decent support for Qt projects too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My CMake template:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

project(qttest)
set(PROJECT_VERSION 0.0.1)

if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1y -pthread -fno-permissive -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -fPIC")
endif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")

set(QT_VERSION_REQ "5.2")

find_package(Qt5Core ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5DBus ${QT_VERSION_REQ} REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

list(APPEND SOURCES
)

list(APPEND MAIN_SOURCES
    main.cpp
    ${SOURCES}
)

list(APPEND LIBS
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Quick
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::DBus
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MAIN_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

Comment: Ok. I accept answer, but add also strings for generating ui files set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
include_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )