# Qt Creator + CMake not parsing files

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, cmake

I am trying to set up CMake and Qt. However, even a simple fresh project doesn't parse. I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415761/using-cmake-with-qt-creator), but no dice. The logs seem to indicate that there is a problem finding jom.exe, so I also added the related path to the PATH variable.

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(CMake_test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(CMake_test
  main.cpp
  mainwindow.cpp
  mainwindow.h
  mainwindow.ui
)

target_link_libraries(CMake_test PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
```

**CMakeLists.txt ([Modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415761/using-cmake-with-qt-creator)):**

```
file(GLOB SRC . *.cpp)
add_executable(CMake_test ${SRC})
```

**CMakeError.log**

```
Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):jom /nologo cmTC_b431b\fast && The system cannot find the file specified
Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: jom /nologo cmTC_b431b\fast && 

Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):jom /nologo cmTC_b7633\fast && The system cannot find the file specified
Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: jom /nologo cmTC_b7633\fast && 

Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):jom /nologo cmTC_cfa37\fast && The system cannot find the file specified
Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: jom /nologo cmTC_cfa37\fast && 

Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):jom /nologo cmTC_33aea\fast && The system cannot find the file specified
Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: jom /nologo cmTC_33aea\fast && 

Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):jom /nologo cmTC_44869\fast && The system cannot find the file specified
Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: jom /nologo cmTC_44869\fast &&
```

**CMakeOutput.log**

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.18362 - AMD64
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: D:/Tools/Programming/Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was: 
0
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28316 for x64

CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.24.28316.0

/out:CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe 
CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj 


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb    /qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/3.15.3/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: D:/Tools/Programming/Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe 
Build flags: /DWIN32;/D_WINDOWS;/W3;/GR;/EHsc
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28316 for x64

CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.24.28316.0

/out:CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe 
CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj 


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/3.15.3/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: D:/Tools/Programming/Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe 
Build flags: /DWIN32;/D_WINDOWS;/W3;/GR;/EHsc
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28316 for x64

CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.24.28316.0

/out:CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe 
CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj 


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/3.15.3/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: D:/Tools/Programming/Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe 
Build flags: /DWIN32;/D_WINDOWS;/W3;/GR;/EHsc
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28316 for x64

CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.24.28316.0

/out:CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe 
CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj 


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/3.15.3/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: D:/Tools/Programming/Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe 
Build flags: /DWIN32;/D_WINDOWS;/W3;/GR;/EHsc
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28316 for x64

CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.24.28316.0

/out:CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe 
CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj 


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Users/xips/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-JKugQb/qtc-cmake-MpAHVTrV/CMakeFiles/3.15.3/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"
```

Comment: What command and options did you use to run CMake? Are you pointing to a different CXX compiler than the default one provided via Visual Studio?

Comment: Please, show not only the log files, but the **configuration error** (produced by CMake) too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I (kind off) figured out what was wrong. After adding jom.exe to the PATH variable I restarted my computer and Qt - however, it still didn't work. I then posted my question. A while after that I opened up Qt again and the project parsed successfully.

I then still had to deal with the error "A CMake tool must be setup for building. Configure a CMake tool in the kit options". But that was also fixable by closing and opening Qt again.

From that point on building and running any project worked without errors.